# PM2 Start Appname Returning Error Cannot Find Modules in Ubuntu 16

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, pm2

this is my first time using node js, and i found a complicated problem, i was thinking this issue because of yarn, so i've removed yarn package but still got the error in my log when i run `sudo pm2 start myAppName`

this is message i've got :

```
0|myAppName |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|myAppName |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
0|myAppName |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
0|myAppName |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
0|myAppName | Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/html/myAppName'
0|myAppName |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(module.js:547:15)
0|myAppName |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
0|myAppName |     at Object.<anonymous> 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:75:21)
0|myAppName |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
0|myAppName |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
0|myAppName |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
0|myAppName |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|myAppName |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
0|myAppName |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
0|myAppName |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
```

the libraries and etc i believe is already installed in node_modules,

maybe you guys have a solution for my problem, should i use another `command` like `pm2` ? or another else ?

please help, i will be appreciated

thanks anyway :)

Comment: `var/www/html/myAppName` is there any directory?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean ? that `path` is my project directory

Comment: Can you verify your project directory path? It seems your project is not there on that path

Comment: hmm, i see, my `node_modules` folder inside this path : `var/www/html/myAppName/app/`, but now how to change the path `var/www/html/myAppName` in the log message ?

Comment: If myAppName has a valid package.json file. Then you can simply run `npm install` to install dependencies.

Comment: If myAppName has a valid package.json file. Then you can simply run `npm install` to install dependencies.

Comment: sorry but seems like you dont get my problem, i've already has a node_modules file from executing `npm install` command in `var/www/html/myAppName/app/` but the error log said, not found modules in path `var/www/html/myAppName`, so maybe how to redirecting `path pm2` from `var/www/html/myAppName` to `var/www/html/myAppName/app/` ??

Answer (score 2):

now i get it, the problem is not about the path, in my case, i just execute command `sudo pm2 update`, and the error log in `pm2` was gone.

thanks